# AJAX response is always 405

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have an AJAX post

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/rating/save",
        data: JSON.stringify(rating),
        dataType: "json",
        mimeType: "application/json",
        success: function (responseData) {
            console.log(responseData);
            window.location.href = "/welcome"
        },
        error: function (responseData) {
            console.log(responseData);
        }
    });
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class RatingController {
........
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rating/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<Object> saveRating(@RequestBody List<RatingDTO> ratingDTO) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(ratingService.save(ratingDTO),HttpStatus.OK);
        }
}
```

Each time that I'm trying to process the response from the controller even if there is no exception I got

```
status: 405
statusText: "error"
```

The error says that the method is not allowed, but service from this endpoint works great.

Comment: log `ResponseEntity<>(ratingService.save(ratingDTO),HttpStatus.OK)` and check the value

Comment: `<200 OK,[Rating{id=53, score=2.2, stageOfApprove=0, comment='null', date=Thu Mar 14 09:30:13 EET 2019}],{}>`

Comment: TRy removing         mimeType: "application/json",

Comment: Do you have Jackson in your classpath?

Answer (score 1):

You should set POST via `method` attribute:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  ...
```

Comment: the same result, maybe the problem of the library that I'm using? https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: @TarasDanylchenko Did you try it with the latest jQuery?

Comment: Yes, 3.3.1 is the latest jQuery version, i tried with this http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js and got same result

Comment: @TarasDanylchenko your ajax looks well so, maybe you can check if the server responses correctly. Try some client, Postman, or curl: `curl -X POST <url>`

Comment: So, the problem is on the server side. Check out the log, maybe your find a problem there.

Comment: any idea what can be the problem?